# Remove elements in a vector that are greater than value

Tags: r

I need to remove elements (that I am plotting with error bars, so I need to remove that data point from all four vectors below) where the `diff` vector is greater than 2*std. Here was my thought:

```
for (i in 1:length(Z)){
  if (diff[[i]]>=(2*std)){
    Z[[i]] <- NULL
    ucl[[i]] <- NULL
    lcl[[i]] <- NULL
    x[[i]] <- NULL
    }
}
```

The for loop stops completely after it enters the if statement for the first time. I have learned R completely on my own, so please respond to me as if I know next to nothing.

Comment: Please make this reproducible, by including sample data.  As it is, it is difficult to see what you're asking.  Do you have a few related data frames, `Z`, `ucl`, `lcl` and `x`?

Comment: You don't want to try sticking `NULL` into vectors. `NULL` is a semi-special value, but is not the same as reducing the vector by removing values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a for loop. Do something like this if you want to replace certain values by NA:

```
Z[diff >= 2*std] = NA
```

Alternatively, if you want to just filter out the rows that don't satisfy the condition, subset only the rows you want:

```
Z <- Z[diff < 2*std]
```

Comment: Substituting `NA` is not the same as *removing* data points.  If I interpret the OP's question correctly,  She would be better off with `Z <- Z[diff< 2*std]`

Comment: Simplefish, that is wrong wrong wrong. bad advise.